# Why can't a string literal initializer list for a std::vector create a std::vector<std::string> in C++?

Tags: c++, c++17, template-argument-deduction

In C++, if I do:

```
std::vector words {"some","test","cases","here"};
```

- Can anyone explain why `words` is not a `std::vector<std::string>` type of container?
- Isn't C++ supposed to deduct the type through the initializer-list I gave?
- If "some", "test" are not string literals, what do std::string literals look like?

Comment: what type should it deduce? You are aware that some of the literals are of different type?

Comment: Do you know what the type of a string literal is?

Comment: I think the issue is clearer with integer values. The compiler would not know which integer type to use.

Comment: @formerlyknownas_463035818 Well, aren't `"some","test,"cases"` are of std::string type? I write `std::string x = "Hello"` and it works without any issue. What am I missing here?

Comment: @S.K. integer literals have a type and this would work with them.

Comment: Could be `char array1[] = "Foo" "bar";` or a char pointer as well, no?

Comment: using namespace std::string_literals;
std::vector words {"some"s,"test"s,"cases"s,"here"s};

Comment: String literals are not std::string.

Comment: No, "some", "test" or "cases" are not std::strings, they are const char *

Comment: @Mär Wow, does c++ still consider "Foo" as char* and not a std::string by default? So how come does `std::string myStr = "sampletext"` work without any issue?

Comment: @Hui Hey I tried your `"something"s` and it surprisingly works! Could you please elaborate what's going on here. (Probably as an answer, I'll mark this solved since it's exactly what I was looking for)

Comment: @SuperG280 no they are not `const char *`, they are... well see the answer

Comment: @UtkarshGupta `std::string myStr = "sampletext"` you declare type, can't be ambiguous or something else. I suppose it passes a C-string to `std::string` constructor and then builds an `std::string` - but I am not sure about this.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

a [string literal](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/string_literal), like `"something"`, is a c-string.  It creates a `const char[N]` with static storage duration where `N` is the number of characters plus a null terminator.  That means when you do

```
std::vector words {"some","test","cases","here"};
```

What you've done is create a `std::vector<const char*>` since arrays can decay to pointers.

If you want a `std::vector<std::string>` then what you need is to use the [`std::string` user defined literal](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/operator%22%22s).  That would look like

```
using namespace std::string_literals;
std::vector words {"some"s,"test"s,"cases"s,"here"s};
```

and now you have actually `std::string`s that the compiler will use to deduce the type of the vector.

Comment: Note that std::string user defined literals are only available from c++ 14 (which is fine here given OP's C++17 tag, but good to note for future readers)